# Can I run my Ember CLI tests in the browser on my Jenkins CI server?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to get my CI server to run my ember-cli test suite. By default, `ember test` runs the tests using PhantomJS.

Is it possible to have the command use qunit instead, pop open a browser, and return with the appropriate status code?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to trigger phantomJS from your CI build and parse the return value to decide weather to break the build or not ?

Comment: Phantom is missing `.bind` and is finicky in other areas. I suppose I could just use a shim lib, but figured I'd ask the question in case there was a way